# Joining two or more tables in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 tables Ledgers, Accounts, Users and organisation

I am trying to get accounts using ledger Id for each specific user.

```
Table Ledgers contains - LedgerID, Organisation ID
Table Accounts contains  - AccountID, AccountName, LedgerID
Table Users contains - UserID, name
Table Organisation contains - OrganisationId, UserID, organisation name
```

Heres my models.

```
class Accounts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ledger
end

class Ledger < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  belongs_to :organisation
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organisations
end
```

Here is what i have tried.

```
def show
  if authenticated_user
  @Usersorganisations = @authenticated_user.organisations
  # This gets the user's organisations
  @ledger_id = Ledger.where("organisation_id = ?", @Usersorganisations.pluck(:id))

  render json: @ledger_id.as_json
end
```

But trying this gives me PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:

Comment: can you please post error log

Comment: Its a good idea to post code examples as actual runnable code and indent it properly. You might want use an except of schema.rb as that would eliminate the question if you have setup the tables properly in the first place and not in camelCase as in your question text. In general code is always better than text that describes what code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code above is that `@Usersorganisations.pluck(:id)` returns an array, and you're trying to do an sql comparison `=` instead of using the `IN` operator.

You can overcome this in the code you have above by simply changing that line to:

```
@ledger_id = Ledger.where(organisation_id: @Usersorganisations.pluck(:id))
```

A better approach might be to use the rails [has many through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) where you define the association in User such as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organisations
  has_many :ledgers, through: :organisations
end
```

after which, you can simply do the following in your controller:

```
@ledgers = @authenticated_user.ledgers
```